# Firefox 56 for Ubuntu - delete search bar in Bookmarks sidebar

Tags: firefox

When Firefox got updated last month a very, very annoying behavior started.

Every time I start a new browser the cursor moves from the address bar at the top into the SEARCH bar in the bookmarks menu.

I start typing the address and all of a sudden I start searching in the bookmarks instead. Who the h-ll added that feature???

How do I delete the search bar from the bookmarks menu in the sidebar?

Comment: This doesn't happen to me, though I'm using the beta version of Firefox. However, try opening Firefox in safe mode and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, it may be an Addon that is messing up your Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 57 that got installad today did the trick!

Thank you godzillers.

Oh happy days! *The biggest church choir is singing in the background and the heavenly orchestra does its best performance ever*